# Practical ways of dealing with duplicate accounts using OAUTH in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Say that I've got the Facebook, Google, and Username/Password login packages in Meteor. A user with an email of `none@example.com` signs up using this email and password. Then later he forgets that he has signed up before, and signs up again using Facebook. His Facebook email is also `none@example.com`.

So now we've got one person with two different accounts. This is bad and confusing, especially if the user logs in using Facebook and can't find his user data like order history which he had created under the Email/Password system.

Is there a package out there that allows a user to mix and match login methods but still maintaining continuity?

I didn't like that OAUTH users had their emails buried inside `services.google/facebook.email` and instead want it to just be inside the normal `emails` array.

```
var returnUserEmail = function(userDoc){
    if(userDoc.services.google){
        return userDoc.services.google.email;
    } else if (userDoc.services.facebook){
        return userDoc.services.facebook.email;
    } else {
        return userDoc.emails[0].address;
    };
};

Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

    console.log("user created! ", user);

    if (!user.emails){
        var email = returnUserEmail(user);
        user.emails = [];
        user.emails[0] = {};
        user.emails[0].address = email;
        user.emails[0].verified = true;
        // This function simply updates the user document
        updateCollectionDocument(Meteor.users, user);
    };

  return user;

});
```

With this bit of code running, if a user signs up first using email/password and then tries to sign up using Facebook, the login screen will give him an error message saying that the email already exists. And now he *cannot* enjoy the benefits of signing in with Facebook.

So now something doesn't feel right to me. Is there a logic flow where I can have all of these login/registration methods work together but also maintain continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this package https://github.com/splendido/meteor-accounts-meld

> accounts-meld tried to address the following aspects:
>
> 1. No two accounts registered with the same email address can exist
> 2. Many different 3rd-party login services could be associated with the same
>    user account
> 3. Different accounts created in different times referring
>    to the same email address might/should be melded together.

I have used it before and it works great, My work flow was to force email verification (important) after that account-meld can merge accounts with the same emails to one and the user can use the social login. (Also it's possible to ask the user if they want to do that)

Answer (score 0):

I met this situation before. I have come up with following pattern.

1. If user is logged in, use $update operation to bind Facebook to **user.services**
2. If user isn't logged in, try to create a new account by copying email from Facebook document to **user.emails** as you did. User will be warned if the email is already exist but I think it is much acceptable.